# I deployed my war file on openshift, now when every time I type the url "http://todo-aformango.rhcloud.com" it leads to a blank page.

Tags: web-applications, openshift, war

But when I type "http://todo-aformango.rhcloud.com/first-web-app1/" it leads to my index page. 
I want only typing "http://todo-aformango.rhcloud.com/" should lead to my index page. My war file name is  "first-web-app1". Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of your war file to "ROOT.war" if you want it deployed at the root context, which is "http://todo-aformango.rhcloud.com/"

Answer (score 0):

thanks developercorey, but I tried renaming war file to ROOT.war but it didn't work. Then I found that changing the context path resolved my issue

```
<Context path="/" docBase="first-web-app1" reloadable="true">
         <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
         <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
       </Context>
```